# Supress value in particular column in oracle BI

Tags: business-intelligence

[image]

I want to supress the encircled value in whole column.

Comment: what tool are you using? some of the reporting tools have an SQL view check. please verify the underlying query add filters accordingly to remove the desired row.

Comment: @NK0709....I'm using oracle business intelligence tool and the row you want me to remove is there due to because I have  not group it by reprenentative to column, as it is the seperate data for location column kanpur, 
so I wan't it to be supress to the whole column but due to not grouped by representative to , it is lying down as a seperate row there. Can you tell me the solution for this?

Comment: @NK0709....Waiting for you reply

Comment: As I see the representative information is blank may be it is written against a default or unknown value can't you filter this record in the tool .. haven't worked on tool but you should definately have a way to filter to remove the records with  unknown value  of representatives